# How can I allow Rails to accept either a nested object or an empty array for the same attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, axios

**Short Version of Question**

How should my Rails params be set to permit either an empty array or a nested object for the same attribute when receiving a PUT request?

I work for a government contractor and can't put the real code anywhere public, so all code shown is a mock version that should allow readers to understand the problem without revealing any non-public information

**Background**

I've been assigned a bugfix at work. There is a React app that communicates with Rails via Axios. There is also a very complex mathematical model in Java that the React app calls on to perform calculations. The Java portion is not relevant to this question except for the fact that it blocks the easiest solution to my current problem

In the React app, users can add optional attributes to an object. This object will be referred to as `splat`.

`splat` has a number of required attributes and several optional attributes, although only 1 is pertinent to this question. When the optional attributes haven't been set for an instance of `splat`, they are set to an empty array. Here is an example of `splat` with the optional attribute not added.

```
splat = {
required1: x,
required2: y,
required3: z,
required4: {},
optional1: [],
}
```

Here is an example of `splat` with an optional attribute set:

```
splat = {
required1: x,
required2: y,
required3: z,
required4: {},
optional1: {
  sub1: {
   unit: deg,
   value: 45
  },
  sub2: {
   unit: ft,
   value: 1
  },
  sub3: {
   unit: ft,
   value: 10
  } 
 }
}
```

As you can see, once `optional1` is set it becomes a nested object. This all works fine, with new instances of `splat` being properly created when a `POST` request is sent to the splat_controller in Rails. `PUT` requests successfully update `splat` when optional attributes are added.

**The Problem**

Users should be able to remove the optional attributes from instances of `splat` after adding/saving them, but they can't. The values of the optional attributes can be successfully modified, but they can't be removed (modification is not an acceptable solution).

When a user goes to remove `optional1`, the network request payload (visible through the browser) shows that it has indeed been set back to an empty array. However, the response to the `PUT` request that was supposed to remove the value shows a nested object, meaning `optional1` wasn't actually removed from the instance of `splat`.

Here is part of `splat_controller` (the `update` method and params, which is all that should be needed to answer this question):

```
def update
 if @splat&.update(splat_params)
  render json: @splat
 elsif @splat
  render json: @splat.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
 else
  render json: 'resource not found', status: :not_found
end
```

```
def splat_params
 params.permit(
  :required1,
  :required2,
  :required3,
  required4: {},
  optional1: {}
 )
end
```

**What I Know So Far**

This issue is a result of Rails expecting a nested object once `optional1` has been set. The sending of `[]` in the put request essentially results in a "miss", leaving `optional1` a nested object.

All other edits made to an instance of `splat` work fine (required attributes can be modified, optional attributes can be added and their values modified).

**Attempted Solutions**

1. List `optional1` twice in params, like so:

```
def splat_params
params.permit(
 :required1,
 :required2,
 :required3,
 required4: {},
 optional1: {},
 optional1: []
)
end
```

This made no difference.

2. Use `null`/`nil` instead of `[]` for the values of the optional attributes when they aren't set. This does solve the problem, but creates many other issues in doing so and is thus not a viable solution.

Comment: Please forgive code formatting errors, I had to post this question from my personal computer as my work computer does not allow posting on StackOverflow. I did my best to get the formatting/indents right.

Answer (score 0):

You must ask if params['optional1'] is an array or hash:

```
 # preparing environment for tests

x, y, z = "x", "y", "z"

splat = {
  required1: x,
  required2: y,
  required3: z,
  required4: {},
  optional1: [],
}

pp splat[:optional1] if splat[:optional1].is_a?(Array) # asks if optional1 is an array

deg, ft = "deg", "ft"

splat = {
  required1: x,
  required2: y,
  required3: z,
  required4: {},
  optional1: {
    sub1: {
      unit: deg,
      value: 45,
    },
    sub2: {
      unit: ft,
      value: 1,
    },
    sub3: {
      unit: ft,
      value: 10,
    },
  },
}

pp splat[:optional1] if splat[:optional1].is_a?(Hash) # asks if optional1 is a hash

# end of preparing tests


def splat_params
  if params["optional1"].is_a?(Array)
    params.permit(
      :required1,
      :required2,
      :required3,
      required4: {},
      optional1: [],
    )
  end

  if params["optional1"].is_a?(Hash)
    params.permit(
      :required1,
      :required2,
      :required3,
      required4: {},
      optional1: {},
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, gonna give it a try. Is the preparing environment for tests intended to go in the `splat_controller` file as well, or just the modified params section?

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention in the question: There's a JSON schema file specifying that `optional1` should be an object. Should I be expecting to modify that as well? I apologize for all the questions; I'm a front end dev with light Rails experience, but I got assigned this ticket since the Rails guy is on vacation.

Comment: I included tests to show (is_a? function) running: you do not need it! I can't answer 2nd question! Sorry! You may show json file and where it is called.

Comment: I tried your solution out and it lead to errors where the params couldn't be accessed by the other methods in `splat_controller`. The params are under `private`, but the original params are also private and can be accessed by the other methods. I don't know what causes the difference, but I've also never used conditional params before.